# Google Script- If Statement not comparing dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

This if statement is not working.

```
 for (var ccc = 0; ccc <= LastRCrow; ccc++) {    
 if (ConDatesValues[ccc] < DateNow) {
     hideRowValue = ccc + 5;
     ConDatesValues2 = ConDatesValues[ccc];
     Browser.msgBox(ConDatesValues[ccc], Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);           
  }
```

The DateNow value is set at 1379203200000 (Epoch Time) and the ConDatesValues[0] is set at Sun Mar 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT).

I don't think it returns a value. When I tried to output a certain value if it returned true and another value if it was false, it didn't return anything at all.

Do I need to convert one to another format?

Answer (score 0):

in your comparison you can use

```
new Date(ConDatesValues[ccc]).getTime()
```

which returns also the native value (in milliseconds since the "epoch")

so that you can test **==**, **>** and **<** as you want.

be sure that your `dateNow` is really of the same type, if not then use the same procedure :

```
new Date(dateNow).getTime()
```